# HttpClient handler could not recognize the credentials of the X509 Certificate

Tags: c#, docker, x509certificate, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to Deploy custom IoTEdge Module(from Windows container) which creates new HttpClientHandler() and adds the X509Certificate certificate(pfx file) to it.The code I am using for that is:

```
 httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

Then it queries an API by creating the new instance of httpclient

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)){}
```

Everything works fine when I test it locally but I get exception when I deploy this IoTEdge Module.That is when it tries to create HttpClient, it throws the following exception:

```
threw Exception The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized : stack trace    at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCHANNEL_CRED secureCredential)...
```

Note:I have given the full permissions to certificate and certificate has private key.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried to deploy an Edge module that used httpClientHander and I could not get it to work. I gave up and wrote it in JavaScript instead.

Comment: Same question asked on MSDN [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/466e25d8-8288-48b8-a3b0-d2c21663733d/httpclient-handler-could-not-recognize-the-credentials-of-the-x509-certificate?forum=iotedge) for reference